# Passing SpringBoot application properties to a dependency jar

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application along with a `application.properties` file in "`src/main/resources`" folder. I have a custom Servlet filter as a independent jar that will go as a dependency in the above Spring boot Application as part of maven dependency. The Custom Servlet filter requires a property (e.g. version) to get it passed form the Spring boot main App "`application.properties`".

My question is, how do I pass the `version` from my Spring boot application properties to a jar? I tried with `@Value`, but it always give me null.

Sample Snippet:

The Filter

```
package hello;  //delibaretly made the same package as Spring boot App

//Valid Spring Imports

@Component 
public class VersionFilter implements Filter {

    @Value("${version}")
    private String version;  //This always returns null.

    FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = fConfig;
    }
}
```

Sample App from https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ and where I have added the above filter as a jar in the pom. Also, added version key in "application.properties".

Filter Registartion Bean as part of Springboot App

```
package hello;

//Valid Spring Imports

import hello.VersionFilter;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
   //Register VersionFilter     
   @Bean
   public FilterRegistrationBean<VersionFilter> abcFilter() {
       FilterRegistrationBean<VersionFilter> filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

       filterRegBean.setFilter(new VersionFilter());
       filterRegBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1 );    

       return filterRegBean;
   }
}
```

//Updated WebConfig: But how to set Order ? -- Now, with the Order

```
 import hello.VersionFilter;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
   //Register VersionFilter 

    @Autowired
    private VersionFilter versionFilter;

    public FilterRegistrationBean<VersionFilter> abcFilter() {
       FilterRegistrationBean<VersionFilter> filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<VersionFilter>();

       filterRegBean.setFilter(versionFilter);
       filterRegBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1 );        

       return filterRegBean;
   }    
}
```

Comment: take a look at this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I had a look there, but no results

Comment: Remove all the annotation from your `VersionFilter` they add nothing (except noise). Instead of `new VersionFilter()` in the `abcFilter` create another `@Bean` definition for the `VersionFilter` and inject the filter into the `FilterRegistrationBean`. Currently the `VersionFilter` isn't managed by Spring and as such doesn't receive any special Spring treatment.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. Now I can see the version property value. But how to set the order? Also, I am wondering do I really need  the WebConfig class at all? (Actually I took WebConfig reference from some other reference code)

Comment: OK. I made the changes and seems perfect for me atleast. I kept @Component in VersionFilter and that should be fine . Thanks Deinum for the pointers and accept it as a solution.